# SQL query to linq statement

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I need a SQL-query to be a LINQ-statement in my C# code.

```
select 
    item,
    MAX(aph.date) as MaxDate 
from
    Table2.dbo.price aph 
where 
    item in (57269, 57270, 57278, 57279, 57280, 57281)
group by 
    item
```

Any ideas?

I have tried using a list that holds the numbers. Then if it contains select a new item entitie.

I get it to work but the only problem is that i only get the first value from the hardcoded list.

What I have come up with:

```
  var q = new List<decimal>() {57269, 57270, 57278, 57279, 57280, 57281};
        var msdB = new Entities();

        var query = from x in msdB.table1
            where q.Contains(x.q)
            select new Entitie
            {
                Name = x.q,
                MaxDate = x.date
            };

        var q = new List<Entitie> {query.MaxBy(x => x.MaxDate)};


        return q;
```

I want ALL the itemsnumbers in my list to show. Now only the first one shows. (57269).

This get the output of:

57269, 2015-02-18

I want it to be ALL numbers with the dates.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and results? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Show what you have tried - I'm betting you're _very_ close.

Comment: You've just forgotton the `group by` - its in your sql but not your LINQ

Comment: Where is the best place to put it?

Comment: Why is it a decimal if it's only integers?

Comment: I mean decimals of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sql query groups by `item`, your LINQ query needs to do the same

```
var query = from x in msdB.table1
        where q.Contains(x.q)
        group x by x.q into g
        select new Entitie
        {
            Name = g.Key,
            MaxDate = g.Max(v => v.date)
        };
```

[How to: Group Query Results (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545971.aspx)

Comment: Thanks that did the job. But I would like to mark something, when using a object with multiple properties this does not work. With object I mean class public class object ( public string name etc..) You have to use only one property and get the properties from the database object( variable g in this context).

Comment: @user3410846 - you can `group by ` multiple fields, this example like the original just groups on one particular field.

Comment: Okay, maybe I was unclear. In this context I needed to select data from the database into object-properties(later I would call this with ajax through jQuery). 
  Object = g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault() Then in the jQuery I can use data[i].WhateverTheObjectName is to get specific column name from the object. Without using multiple properties in the C#-class.